# AppleScript 'choose from list' - I'm having trouble with Multiple Selections

Tags: applescript

I have a series of AppleScripts which are saved as apps. For simplicity sake let's say the apps are literally named App1, App2, and App3.
I've made a simple list that asks the user to make a selection, then opens that app. It works fine for single selections…

```
choose from list {¬
    "App1", ¬
    "App2", ¬
    "App3"} ¬
    with prompt "What would you like to do?" with multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed

if not result is equal to false then activate application (result as string)
```

But I also need to be able to select multiple apps at the same time and launch them all together (or sequentially).

Currently, if I pick App1 and App3 I get a Choose Application dialog saying "Where is App1App3?" which obviously doesn't exist.

How can I change the code so that it sees the selections as separate apps and launches them correctly?

Comment: This seems remarkably similar in intent to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383193/apple-script-choose-from-list-how-can-i-run-a-different-command-if-multiple-s

Comment: It is, but the solution didn't work in the end. My real life working script needs about 30 apps in that list, and with the previous solution I had to add SO many `does not contain` rules to each `if/then` that it became horribly complex and riddled with errors when I inevitably missed one.  So I thought I'd resubmit with a simpler question, and I'm hoping the solution stays almost as simple as the original script I have. I'm hoping that it's just a matter of editing that last line.

Comment: idk applescript well enough, but in theory, I'd coerce it into a list & iterate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the point where you are having a problem, `result` is a [list](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_574). Try [looping through the items in the list](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-DontLinkElementID_877).

```
set answer to choose from list {¬
    "App1", ¬
    "App2", ¬
    "App3"} ¬
    with prompt "What would you like to do?" with multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed
if answer is not false then
    repeat with appitem in answer
        activate application appitem
    end repeat
end if
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. What does `applic` do? I assume it's short for application? It looks like a variable but I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: I wanted to use `application` or `item`, but these are the names of a classes. So I needed to choose something else. Settled on using `appitem` for the variable name.

Comment: Awesome thanks. This is a simplified version of a script I'm trying to write, and it helps tremendously. Next I would like to scale it up to about 30 items in the list. For the multiple selections I would like it to just select a *different app* rather than run multiple apps sequentially. A solution was posted in the link here but I need a different answer that simply acts on my selection and EXCLUDES all other choices. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383193/apple-script-choose-from-list-how-can-i-run-a-different-command-if-multiple-s

Comment: What a coincidence! I was wrestling with the same problem, and here's the answer! +1  :)